# Different response in my browser vs the API Testing Console

Tags: javascript, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently new in Cognitive services. Yesterday I tried Computer vision API where I got different JSON response for the same [image](http://activeforlife.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/co-ed-kids-playing-soccer.jpg) in the API Testing console to that when I used the javascript code in my browser. I have enclosed my javascript code and the screenshot of the two different responses.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myKey = "my key";
    var myBody = {url:"http://activeforlife.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/co-ed-kids-playing-soccer.jpg"}
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            // Request parameters
            "maxCandidates": "1",

        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", myKey);
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: JSON.stringify(myBody),
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>

<h4 id="ans"></h4>


</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot for the different outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLJmq.png)

Comment: You are opening a file in the second image?!

Comment: Sorry didn't get that. I am not opening rather I am using the above mentioned code to call the API in my browser in the right side browser of my image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cognitive Service Vision API will perform different visual classifications depending on the `visualFeatures` query parameter.  You can find more details [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa).

If you don't specify any features, you are performing the equivalent of `visualFeatures=Categories` (your example).  The console appears to have been executed with `visualFeatures=Description`.  You can set the feature list in your `param` object.